# Days, hours, minutes since timestamp

Tags: php

So I have this function, which displays how long it's been since a timestamp.

Right now if it's been let's say 60 minutes, it will go over and show "1 hour ago". If it's been 24 hours it goes over to "1 day ago" and so on. How could I do so that if it's been for example 1 hour, show minutes also?

Like

```
Event occured 58 minutes ago
3 minutes later
Event occured 1 hour 1 minute ago
26 hours later
Event occured 1 day 2 hour ago




function humanTiming($time) 
{

$time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

$tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'month',
    604800 => 'week',
    86400 => 'day',
    3600 => 'hour',
    60 => 'minute',
    1 => 'second'
);

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    return $numberOfUnits.$text.' ago';
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your function like this:

```
function humanTiming($time)
{
    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    $result = '';
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        if ($counter > 2) break;

        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        $result .= "$numberOfUnits $text ";
        $time -= $numberOfUnits * $unit;
        ++$counter;
    }

    return "{$result}ago";
}
```

Check result on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/OQXUu4Xc).

Comment: Thing is I only wanna show 2 items, so in you example i'd only wanna show "3 week 6 day ago"

Comment: @Kaka New update for 'ago' postfix better processing

Comment: Thanks so much! Hey, any way to only print seconds and minutes alone? Like: 59 seconds ago, 59 miutes ago, 1 hour 5 minutes ago

Comment: @Kaka I think it's possible. Ask new question with detailed explanation of your new needs ;)

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.2.0 introduced [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, which will provide a better solution for the problem.

I am going to use [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718155/subtract-some-date-and-time-from-current-date-and-time-to-find-age-in-php/38718499#38718499) on another question to show how easy it is, though will slightly edit the code:

```
$create_time = "2016-08-02 12:35:04";
$current_time="2016-08-02 16:16:02";

$dtCurrent = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time);
// to use current timestamp, use the following:
//$dtCurrent = new DateTime();
$dtCreate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $create_time);
$diff = $dtCurrent->diff($dtCreate);

$interval = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
```

`$interval` will return `0 years 0 months 0 days 3 hours 40 minutes 58 seconds`

Let's get rid of those zero values now. Good old regex is pretty much useful here:

```
$interval = preg_replace('/(^0| 0) (years|months|days|hours|minutes|seconds)/', '', $interval);
```

In the end we get exactly what we need: `3 hours 40 minutes 58 seconds`

Comment: This is by far the nicest solution in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can find Event occurred time and current time difference using diff. For example see the following code

```
$time1 = new DateTime('2013-11-21 12:59:00'); // Event occurred time
$time2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // Current time
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $interval->y . " Year " .$interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds <br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a progressive calculation method such as:

```
$tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'month',
    604800 => 'week',
    86400 => 'day',
    3600 => 'hour',
    60 => 'minute',
    1 => 'second'
);

$tokenValues = array();
foreach($tokens as $tokenValue => $tokenName)
{
    if($time > $tokenValue)
    {
        $tokenValues[$tokenName] = floor($time \ $tokenValue);
        $time -= $tikenValue;
    }
    if(count($tokenValues) == 2)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You should then have only 2 items in tokenValues, adapt as you see fit!

Comment: Note that i haven't tested it, but the logic looks right, it should be something around that that you need

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to explain, but this function works as I tested it. In addition, I add a feature to handle time from the current time and future. If you supply this function with exact current time, it will return `'just now'`. If you supply it with time from the past, it will return a string ended with `'ago'`. If you supply it with time from the future, it will return a string ended with `'later'`. Another feature is automatic singular/plural form for the time unit. Try it yourself!

```
function timeEllapsedFrom($from) {
  $time = time() - $from;
  $diff = abs($time);
  $tokens = array (
    'year' => 31536000,
    'month' => 2592000,
    'week' => 604800,
    'day' => 86400,
    'hour' => 3600,
    'minute' => 60,
    'second' => 1
  );
  $result = array();
  foreach ($tokens as $id => $length) {
    $value = floor($diff/$length);
    if ($value) $result[] = "$value $id" . ($value > 1 ? 's' : '');
    $diff -= $length*$value;
  }
  if (!count($result)) return 'just now';
  return join(', ', $result) . ($time < 0 ? ' later' : ' ago');
}
```

You can test it with this code:

```
echo timeEllapsedFrom(time() - 604800 - 7200 - 480 - 24);
```

and it will output:

```
1 week, 2 hours, 8 minutes, 24 seconds ago
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/datetime) class. Works with both past and future timestamps, and does correct pluralization when needed:

```
function elapsedTime($time)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $given_time = new DateTime("@$time");
    $current_time = new DateTime();
    $diff = $given_time->diff($current_time);
    $timemap = array('y' => 'year',
                     'm' => 'month',
                     'd' => 'day',
                     'h' => 'hour',
                     'i' => 'minute',
                     's' => 'second');
    $timefmt = array();

    foreach ($timemap as $prop => $desc) {
        if ($diff->$prop > 0) {
            $timefmt[] = ($diff->$prop > 1)
                ? "{$diff->$prop} {$desc}s"
                : "{$diff->$prop} $desc";
        }
    }

    return (!$timefmt)
        ? 'just now'
        : ((count($timefmt) > 1)
            ? $diff->format(sprintf('%s and %s',
                implode(', ', array_slice($timefmt, 0, -1)), end($timefmt)))
            : end($timefmt))
            . (($given_time < $current_time) ? ' ago' : ' later');
}
```

Testing:

```
var_dump(elapsedTime(strtotime('1987-11-25 11:40')));
# string(69) "25 years, 11 months, 29 days, 17 hours, 50 minutes and 42 seconds ago"
var_dump(elapsedTime(time()));
# string(8) "just now"
var_dump(elapsedTime(strtotime('2013-11-25')));
# string(41) "18 hours, 29 minutes and 18 seconds later"
```

Comment: where did you define timestamp1 and timestamp2?

Comment: @Kaka Oops, sorry! I've edited variable names after answering and I forgot to update these... Now it's fixed! Did it worked for you? :)