# days, hours, and minutes remaining in php

Tags: php

I have this timestamp from the database `1496592689`

the problem is I don't know how to get the remaining days, hours and minutes

but I have this code bellow

this is my variable from where the timestamp stored `$db_user_timestamp`

and now I have this current time now `$timenow = time();`

I tried to calculate it with

```
$remainingtime = $db_user_timestamp - $timenow;
```

But I don't know how to put it in the days, hours and minutes.

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract some date and time from current date and time to find age in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718155/subtract-some-date-and-time-from-current-date-and-time-to-find-age-in-php)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work for me. It keeps loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$create_time = "1496592689";
$current_time = time();

$dtCurrent = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $current_time);
$dtCreate = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $create_time);
$diff = $dtCurrent->diff($dtCreate);

$interval = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
$interval = preg_replace('/(^0| 0) (years|months|days|hours|minutes|seconds)/', '', $interval);

echo $interval;
```

result

```
 6 months 30 days 5 hours 52 minutes
```

Comment: this one worked
what is the requirement version of the php to use this?

Comment: `5.2.0`. The question I posted as duplicate in the comment doesn't provide a straight answer, it provides a hint and if you wish to be a good programmer, you have to follow, analyze and research hints. Not everyone and not every time will provide a straight-forward answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$db_user_timestamp = 1496592689;
$difference = $db_user_timestamp - time();
echo "Day : ".$day = date('d',$difference);
echo "<br>Hour : ".$hour = date('H',$difference);
echo "<br>Minute : ".$minute = date('i',$difference);
?>
```

Comment: this is useful but not accurate,
it didnt get the exact date

Comment: `date` is outdated and should not be used in OOP anymore. Plus it doesn't always give a precise interval.

Comment: Yes sometime its d-m-y format or H:i:s format, but when users know which timestamp used then its usefull.

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP version is 5.3 or latest, you should check 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
and
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $db_user_timestamp));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours %m minutes %s seconds');
```

Comment: this one worked too
I saw this code but you modified it and its now ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: Will result in `0 years`. Also doing `new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $db_user_timestamp));` is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using date('M/d/Y H:i:s', $theTimestamp); will give you date in day, month, year, hour, minute, seconds in the order you want (change 'M/d/Y H:i:s' to your string depending on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)